# Why does the code at the end give a singular matrix error?

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning

I tried the mixture of Gaussians model and am facing several problems. I have pasted my whole code at ideone. The code is at: https://ideone.com/dNYtZ2

When I try to run fitMixGauss(data, k)), I get a singular matrix error from the function below.

```
    def fitMixGauss(data, k):
"""
Estimate a k MoG model that would fit the data. Incremently plots the outcome.


Keyword arguments:
data -- d by n matrix containing data points.
k -- scalar representing the number of gaussians to use in the MoG model.

Returns: 
mixGaussEst -- dict containing the estimated MoG parameters.

"""

#     MAIN E-M ROUTINE  
#     In the E-M algorithm, we calculate a complete posterior distribution over                                  
#     the (nData) hidden variables in the E-Step.  
#     In the M-Step, we update the parameters of the Gaussians (mean, cov, w).   

nDims, nData = data.shape


postHidden = np.zeros(shape=(k, nData))

# we will initialize the values to random values
mixGaussEst = dict()
mixGaussEst['d'] = nDims
mixGaussEst['k'] = k
mixGaussEst['weight'] = (1 / k) * np.ones(shape=(k))
mixGaussEst['mean'] = 2 * np.random.randn(nDims, k)
mixGaussEst['cov'] = np.zeros(shape=(nDims, nDims, k))
for cGauss in range(k):
    mixGaussEst['cov'][:, :, cGauss] = 2.5 + 1.5 * np.random.uniform() * np.eye(nDims)


# calculate current likelihood
# TO DO - fill in this routine
logLike = getMixGaussLogLike(data, mixGaussEst)
print('Log Likelihood Iter 0 : {:4.3f}\n'.format(logLike))

nIter = 30;

logLikeVec = np.zeros(shape=(2 * nIter))
boundVec = np.zeros(shape=(2 * nIter))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for cIter in range(nIter):

    # ===================== =====================
    # Expectation step
    # ===================== =====================
    curCov = mixGaussEst['cov']                                                                                  
    curWeight = mixGaussEst['weight']                                                                            
    curMean = mixGaussEst['mean']
    num= np.zeros(shape=(k,nData))
    for cData in range(nData):
        # TO DO (g) : fill in column of 'hidden' - calculate posterior probability that
        # this data point came from each of the Gaussians
        # replace this:


        thisData = data[:,cData]
        #for c in range(k):
        #    num[c] = mixGaussEst['weight'][c] * (1/((2*np.pi)**(nDims)*np.linalg.det(mixGaussEst['cov'][:,:,c]))**(1/2))*np.exp(-0.5*(np.transpose(thisData-mixGaussEst['mean'][:,c])))@np.linalg.inv(mixGaussEst['cov'][:,:,c])@(thisData-mixGaussEst['mean'][:,c])


        thisdata = data[:,cData];
        denominatorExp = 0
        for j in range(k):
            mu = curMean[:,j]
            sigma = curCov[:,:,j]
            curNorm = (1/((2*np.pi)**(nDims)*np.linalg.det(sigma))**(1/2))*np.exp(-0.5*(np.transpose(thisData-mu)))@np.linalg.inv(sigma)@(mu)
            num[j,cData] = curWeight[j]*curNorm
            denominatorExp = denominatorExp + num[j,cData]

        postHidden[:, cData] = num[:,cData]/denominatorExp


    # ===================== =====================
    # Maximization Step
    # ===================== =====================
    # for each constituent Gaussian
    for cGauss in range(k):
        # TO DO (h):  Update weighting parameters mixGauss.weight based on the total
        # posterior probability associated with each Gaussian. Replace this:
        #mixGaussEst['weight'][cGauss] = mixGaussEst['weight'][cGauss]
        sum_Kth_Gauss_Resp = np.sum(postHidden[cGauss,:])

        mixGaussEst['weight'][cGauss] = sum_Kth_Gauss_Resp /np.sum(postHidden)




        #mixGaussEst['weight'][cGauss] = np.sum(postHidden[cGauss,:])/sum(sum(postHidden[:,:]));






        # TO DO (i):  Update mean parameters mixGauss.mean by weighted average
        # where weights are given by posterior probability associated with
        # Gaussian.  Replace this:
        #mixGaussEst['mean'][:,cGauss] = mixGaussEst['mean'][:,cGauss]
        numerator = 0
        for j in range(nData):
            numerator = numerator + postHidden[cGauss,j]*data[:,j]
        numerator = np.dot( postHidden[cGauss,:],data[0,:])
        mixGaussEst['mean'][:,cGauss] = numerator / sum_Kth_Gauss_Resp


        # TO DO (j):  Update covarance parameter based on weighted average of
        # square distance from update mean, where weights are given by
        # posterior probability associated with Gaussian
        #mixGaussEst['cov'][:,:,cGauss] = mixGaussEst['cov'][:,:,cGauss]
        muMatrix = mixGaussEst['mean'][:,cGauss]
        muMatrix = muMatrix.reshape((2,1))
        numerator = 0
        for j in range(nData):

            kk=data[:,j]
            kk.reshape((2,1))
            numerator_i = postHidden[cGauss,j]*(kk-muMatrix)@np.transpose(kk-muMatrix)
            numerator = numerator + numerator_i

        mixGaussEst['cov'][:,:,cGauss] = numerator /sum_Kth_Gauss_Resp

        # draw the new solution

    drawEMData2d(data, mixGaussEst)
    time.sleep(0.7)
    fig.canvas.draw()

    # calculate the log likelihood
    logLike = getMixGaussLogLike(data, mixGaussEst)
    print('Log Likelihood After Iter {} : {:4.3f}\n'.format(cIter, logLike))


return mixGaussEst
```

Log likelihood give nan and why does the whole code(in ideone) at the end give a singular matrix error.

Comment: try performing a nansum in the likelihood with a list comprehension.

Comment: Could you tell me about the singular matrix error? I fixed the NaN problem

Comment: Your matrix is not invertible, you could add a little bit of noise or use pseudoinverse

Comment: @UjjayantaBhaumik While running the EM algorithm for GMM curve fitting, if data points are equal to the mean then the exponential part (x - mean)^2 will be equal to zero and the whole function will only depend upon variance which will try to be zero and maximise the whole function to infinity. So, the best practice to remove these errors to add a small amount of noise to your dataset. For more details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359730/169659